# FB like adds WordPress install screen text to the wall

Tags: facebook

I have a site for a client that is behaving very strangely. You can view the site here http://cruisephotofactory.com

When you click the like button in the sidebar instead of using the open graph values the site gives, FB posts the text from the WordPress install screen. This text is 100% not on the site anywhere and anyway the only time it appears is during install, when obviously the FB button was not yet installed or active.

I have the same site, same code, same theme, same everything installed on a  second domain http://cruisephotofactory.it and here I would expect the same thing to happen, only it doesn't. instead it seems to post the wp object on the FB wall.

If I clone the site to a different domain on a different server, everything works fine the problem only seems to be happening on these 2 domains.

I am sure it has to be something blindingly obvious I am missing and I am going to feel really stupid when its pointed out, but blasted if I can figure out how 2 different, repeatable outcomes are happening with the same code and how its getting the install text in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a cache issue. Someone "liked" the page before your WordPress installation was done, Facebook visited the site, copied the WordPress installation page, and cached the result.

It is possible that by using the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) you can refresh the cache.

Comment: Thanks Jan, One thing though: how could someone like the page before installation if the like button was not present at the time? At any rate, it was working fine before, its just in the last couple of weeks its been doing this so it can't have been from install, and that wouldn't explain the .IT site getting the wp-object! Have been using the linter tool. it is showing some other strange behavior as well. On the home page it says the open graph items are missing though they are clearly there in the source and on pages of the site other than home page I get an exception page can not be reached

Comment: Ash: You can like a page without a direct "Like" button on that page, for example with [a browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocfhgijcimpoffgcapmbnheggfgfiime). I think the problem is specific to Facebook, not to WordPress, so you might get better answers on the [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will update the cache in 24hours. You can use the [lint tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) like Jan said and may be my plugin can help you in choosing thumbnails - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like-thumbnail/

Comment: Thumbnails aren't the problem, thanks though. I have it set up to use the featured image as the thumbnail.

Comment: If it shows right info in Lint tool, then I guess the problem must have been solved by now :)